# Django выдаёт ошибку при запуске сервера

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

При запуске сервера вылетает ошибка

```
You have 13 unapplied migration(s). Your project may not work properly until you apply the migrations for app(s): auth, contenttypes, firstapp, sessions.
```

Но сервер всё ещё загружается и позволяет переходить по ссылкам, но css и js в них нет `возможно по другой причине`

при запуске `py manage.py migrations` выдаёт большую ошибку:

```
Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, firstapp, sessions
Running migrations:
Applying contenttypes.0002_remove_content_type_name...Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\gff10\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 86, in _execute
return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "C:\Users\gff10\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py", line 74, in execute
return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
File "C:\Users\gff10\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 209, in execute
res = self._query(query)
File "C:\Users\gff10\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 315, in _query
db.query(q)
File "C:\Users\gff10\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 239, in query
_mysql.connection.query(self, query)
MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError: (1054, "Unknown column 'name' in 'django_content_type'")

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
main()
File "manage.py", line 17, in mainexecute_from_command_line(sys.argv)File "C:\Users\gff10\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_lineutility.execute()File "C:\Users\gff10\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 395, in executeself.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
File "C:\Users\gff10\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 328, in run_from_argv
self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
File "C:\Users\gff10\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 369, in execute
output = self.handle(*args, **options)
File "C:\Users\gff10\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 83, in wrapped
res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\gff10\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 231, in handle
post_migrate_state = executor.migrate(
File "C:\Users\gff10\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 117, in migrate
state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
File "C:\Users\gff10\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 147, in _migrate_all_forwards
state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
File "C:\Users\gff10\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 245, in apply_migration
state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
File "C:\Users\gff10\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\migration.py", line 124, in apply
operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
File "C:\Users\gff10\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\operations\fields.py", line 249, in database_forwards
schema_editor.alter_field(from_model, from_field, to_field)
File "C:\Users\gff10\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 564, in alter_field
self._alter_field(model, old_field, new_field, old_type, new_type,
File "C:\Users\gff10\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 710, in _alter_field
self.execute(
File "C:\Users\gff10\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 142, in execute
cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "C:\Users\gff10\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 100, in execute
return super().execute(sql, params)
File "C:\Users\gff10\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 68, in execute
return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
File "C:\Users\gff10\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 77, in _execute_with_wrappers
return executor(sql, params, many, context)
File "C:\Users\gff10\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 86, in _execute
return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "C:\Users\gff10\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
File "C:\Users\gff10\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 86, in _execute
return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "C:\Users\gff10\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py", line 74, in execute
return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
File "C:\Users\gff10\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 209, in execute
res = self._query(query)
File "C:\Users\gff10\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 315, in _query
db.query(q)
File "C:\Users\gff10\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 239, in query
_mysql.connection.query(self, query)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1054, "Unknown column 'name' in 'django_content_type'")
```

Мне перекинули БД MySQL, с уже созданными столбцами типа django session. MySqlconnector подключал.

Как это исправить?

Comment: У меня есть подозрение, что нужно удалить все папки `migrations` в проектах и попборовать еще разок. Еще я хотел спросить, каким образом можно "перекинуть БД MySQL"?

Comment: Сделали бэкап через dbForge, я этот код запустил, создалась БД

Comment: Ух ты, а зачем? Django сам создает все таблицы и прочее, вам нужно только сделать БД

Answer (score 1):

а база-то наполнена данными? Если нет, просто почисти её, удали все файлы из папок migrations во всех приложениях проекта и снова миграни всё.
Если данные есть, то сначала выгрузи базу и повтори верхний пункт, потом залей базу снова

Comment: Я создал новую бд, в настройках подключил её. Прописал py manage.py makemigrations выдал no changes, прописал migrate выдал огромную ошибку:
"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(6) NOT NULL)' at line 1" Причём тут SQL, если я загружаю в бд свои модели?

Comment: заходи в папку с приложением, там будет папка migrations. нужно удалить из неё все файлы, кроме _init_.py. Сделай так со всеми приложениями проекта и снова makemigrations сделать нужно. Самая легкая база для начинающих - это sqlite, ну или Postgresql. рекомендую начать с неё, а не с MySQL